# AIX x Linux line endings

Tags: linux, aix, character-encoding, conversion

Using Meld to compare two identical files in terms of contents, it give a warning like this:

> **... There was a problem opening the file "...\CHXXXX_...\psart20p.pc".
>          There was an encoding conversion error and it was needed to use a fallback character**

The true question is, despite whether Meld, there some difference between Unix AIX and Linux line endings?

Answer (score 1):

A "fallback character" does not sound right when talking about line endings, but it might apply with character set conversions. Modern Linuxes are overwhelmingly UTF-8 by default, but AIX might still be using one of the ISO-8859-*  character sets.

Please run `locale` on both AIX and Linux and look at the `LC_CTYPE=...` line. What does it say on each system?

Comment: Alternatively, AIX is from IBM, so it might be using EBCDIC...

Comment: The locale in Linux is:
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"

Comment: In AIX the locale is:
LC_CTYPE="en_US"

Comment: So the Linux is definitely using UTF-8, but AIX uses whatever is the default character set for the en_US locale... which might be dependent on AIX version. Modern AIX versions seem to have en_US aliased to en_US.UTF-8, but a very old AIX version (older than 5.2) might have a different default. And even if the AIX OS uses UTF-8, that does not necessarily guarantee that the application that created the file does. The application might be originally programmed with a legacy character encoding, and never updated for UTF-8.